# Django Rest Framework: serialize list of ids

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to serialize request's payload like `{'ids': [1,2,3]}` as a ListField of primary keys (i.e. check by serializer whether Task objects with such ids exist)?

Or what approach should I use to write an API view for another microservice to confirm that tasks were enqueued?

```
serializer = ConfirmationSerializer(
    data=request.data, many=True
)
queryset = Task.objects.filter(
    ids_in=serializer.data.ids,
    status=Task.STATUS_CREATED,
)

queryset.update(
    status=Task.STATUS_SENT,
    confirmed_at=dt.datetime.now()
)
return Response({'status': 'ok'})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) may be used to serialize a list of primary keys. Just pass the `queryset` argument to validate the field input and inside `create` method you will have access to a list of `Task` objects to update

```
class ConfirmationSerializer(Serializer):
    tasks_ids = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, 
        queryset=Task.objects.filter(status=Task.STATUS_CREATED)
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        task_list = validated_data['tasks_ids']

        # Update the tasks here
        update_task_list(task_list)
```

Remember that `task_list` is not a queryset (is a list of `Task` objects), it will not be possible call something like `task_list.update()`. Update action must be performed for each object

Comment: can I ask how would you implement it if the object which I get its queryset (Task in this case) would be one of several possible options? For example, it could be either ids of 'Tasks' or ids of 'Items', according to the request.